# counterpart to PIL's Image.paste in PHP

Tags: php, python, gd, python-imaging-library

I was asked to port a Python application to PHP (and I'm not very fond of PHP).

The part I'm having trouble to port uses a set of monochromatic "template" images based on the wonderful [Map Icons Collection](http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/) by [Nicolas Mollet](http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/author/nico-mollet/). These template images are used to create an icon with custom background and foreground colors. PIL's Image.paste is used to "paste" the icon foreground with the selected color using the template Image as alpha mask. For example:

[image: icon creation]

How can I replicate this in PHP? Is there any alternative besides doing it pixel-by-pixel?

[update]

I'm not proud of my PHP skills... What I've got so far:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/png');

// read parameters: icon file, foreground and background colors
$bgc = sscanf(empty($_GET['bg']) ? 'FFFFFF' : $_GET['bg'], '%2x%2x%2x');
$fgc = sscanf(empty($_GET['fg']) ? '000000' : $_GET['fg'], '%2x%2x%2x');
$icon = empty($_GET['icon']) ? 'base.png' : $_GET['icon'];

// read image information from template files
$shadow = imagecreatefrompng("../static/img/marker/shadow.png");
$bg = imagecreatefrompng("../static/img/marker/bg.png");
$fg = imagecreatefrompng("../static/img/marker/" . $icon);
$base = imagecreatefrompng("../static/img/marker/base.png");
imagesavealpha($base, true); // for the "shadow"

// loop over every pixel
for($x=0; $x<imagesx($base); $x++) {
    for($y=0; $y<imagesy($base); $y++) {
        $color = imagecolorsforindex($bg, imagecolorat($bg, $x, $y));
        // templates are grayscale, any channel serves as alpha
        $alpha = ($color['red'] >> 1) ^ 127; // 127=transparent, 0=opaque.
        if($alpha != 127) { // if not 100% transparent
            imagesetpixel($base, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($base, $bgc[0], $bgc[1], $bgc[2], $alpha));
        }
        // repeat for foreground and shadow with foreground color
        foreach(array($shadow, $fg) as $im) {
            $color = imagecolorsforindex($im, imagecolorat($im, $x, $y));
            $alpha = ($color['red'] >> 1) ^ 127;
            if($alpha != 127) {
                imagesetpixel($base, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($base, $fgc[0], $fgc[1], $fgc[2], $alpha));
            }
        }       
    }
}
// spit image
imagepng($base);
// destroy resources
foreach(array($shadow, $fg, $base, $bg) as $im) {
    imagedestroy($im);
}

?>
```

It's working and performance is not bad.

Comment: Not sure if it is wise to ask PHP developers to assist you whilst also saying you don't like their language ;-)

Comment: If these are PNG images, ImageMagick would be a good way to go, if GD2 cannot do this.

Comment: @halfer: they are free to hate Python :-)

Comment: Heh, true! Let us know how you get on with IM - or if you have any GD2 code that hasn't worked. Have you [seen this](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php)?

Comment: @halfer: I was trying to avoid ImageMagick because it is not installed at the deployment server, and the sponsor is really picky about changing the environment. ImageMagick sounds like good advice, thanks.

Comment: The linked article should be okay with just the default GD installation on any recent version of PHP, imo.

Comment: @halfer: would you make that an answer instead of a comment so I can vote you up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments, ImageMagick would be able to do this. However you've indicated that this may not be non-optimal for your use case, so consider using GD2. There's a demo on how to do [image merging](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php) on the PHP site.

I would guess that this can be done on any (fairly recent) default PHP installation.