# Combine 2 images into 1 Google Maps marker icon

Tags: image-processing, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to combine 2 images into 1 to be used as an icon for a Google Maps marker. One image will be a static image stored on my server (an image placeholder for a profile photo) and the other one will be dynamic (a users profile photo from a third-party site) Basically I want to set the static image as the bottom layer and the dynamic image as the top layer, the idea being to make it look like the profile photo is embedded in the placeholder image.

Anyone have any idea how to do this? The Google Maps API only allows one image as an icon so I will have to combine them somehow prior to added the combined image as the icon to the map. I did think about creating 2 markers one with each image but I am using markerClusterer so this will not work.

Comment: Not exactly the same problem but I had to merge images for a marker before, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467257/counterpart-to-pils-image-paste-in-php

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look now.

Comment: BTW you can see it at work here (try changing the hex RGB colors to see the result): http://produtos.seade.gov.br/mapserver/markers/ffff00/ff0000/airport/marker.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out php has a function *imagecopymerge()* that can do this! Thanks [Paulo Scardine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444036/paulo-scardine), the accepted answer to the question you posted in your comment lead me to the answer.